# what is an inode in case of windows?

Tags: c++

On stackoverflow itself, i found that windows uses  file id like structure similat to inode concept in linux. Inode is nothing but a number. But i dont know whether a file id is a number or pathname or whetever else... But if i want to retreive this file id through cpp program, which function i should use? And if its possible, can i use this function in turbo cpp or visual cpp... In simple words... What should i do to get file id through cpp prog in windows,?

Thanx for reading question...:-)

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article on inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode): "In a Unix-style file system, an index node, informally referred to as an inode, is a data structure used to represent a filesystem object". So no it's not a "number", it's a data structure, and can be different on disk and in memory. On the other hand, it's *represented* as a number to user-space applications, which is quite a different thing. And no, Windows does not have inodes, either as structures nor as numbers.

Comment: If you want to get the raw disk data structures in Windows, you probably can't get them as a regular user, you probably have to have special capabilities enabled for your user and/or program. You also need to search more on your favorite search sites, and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/).

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to inodes, not to file descriptors, sometimes called identifier (id)? In case of descriptors, you can use them by low level file calls as `open` or `dup`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's a question of vocabulary; a lot of early Unix documentation used "inode" when it meant inode number, and of course, all file systems must have something like an inode (although it is often part of the directory structure---Unix is one of the first systems which separated inodes from directory entries, and thus supported hard links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a unique identifier for a file, try the nFileIndexHigh and nFileIndexLow members of the [BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363788) struct, which is populated by [GetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952).